# string concatenation with strncat leads to error in signedness

Tags: c, string, char, concatenation, signedness

*update: the point of whether char, signed char, or unsigned was ultimately moot here.  it was more appropriate to use memcpy in this situation, since it works indiscriminately on bytes.*

Couldn't be a simpler operation, but I seem to be missing a critical step.  In the following code, I am attempting to fill `bufferdata` with `buffer` for which the compiler warns me of a difference in signedness.

```
unsigned char  buffer[4096] = {0};
char *bufferdata;

bufferdata = (char*)malloc(4096 * sizeof(bufferdata));

if (! bufferdata)
  return false;

while( ... )
{
    // nextBlock( voidp _buffer, unsigned _length );
 read=nextBlock( buffer, 4096);

 if( read > 0 )
 {

  bufferdata = strncat(bufferdata, buffer, read); // (help)
  // leads to: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of strncat differ in signedness.

  if(read == 4096) {

   // let's go for another chunk
   bufferdata = (char*)realloc(bufferdata, ( strlen(bufferdata) + (4096 * sizeof(bufferdata)) ) );
   if (! bufferdata) {
    printf("failed to realloc\n");
    return false;
   }

  }

 }
 else if( read<0 )
 {
  printf("error.\n");
  break;
 }
 else {
  printf("done.\n");
  break;    
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you really reading strings ? If so,'buffer' should be char. If not, you shouldn't be using strncat

Comment: +1 for that.  they really aren't strings if nuls are rampant. switched to memcpy and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously in your compiler `char` is `signed char`, thus the warning message.

Comment: That's wrong. You have to use `unsigned char` if you want uninterpreted bytes because only `unsigned char` and unsigned bitfields are guaranteed to be a pure binary representation.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * strncat ( char * destination, char * source, size_t num );
```

so as your destination buffer is unsigned char so there will be a warning of sign. You can either change your buffer to char array if signed is not necessary else you can ignore warnings using -w option in compiler.